# How to load a stylesheet into wp_head from a custom widget?

Tags: widgets, wp-head

The code below is part of a widget that goes with my theme. I'm trying to include a stylesheet that the widget needs by placing an add_action call to wp_head. However, the function never fires in this context.

What am I missing?

```
   function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if(!get_option('my_slider')) return;
        add_action('wp_head', 'my_sliderCSS');
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty($instance['title']) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance );
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $instance['text'], $instance );
        $hide_title = isset( $instance['hide_title'] ) ? $instance['hide_title'] : false;
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( $title && !$hide_title )echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        if ( $text )?><div id="slider"><dl><?php echo $instance['filter'] ? wpautop($text) : $text; ?></dl></div>
        <?php echo $after_widget;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean that `my_sliderCSS` does not fire? I'm afraid that `wp_head` has long fired off before your `widget()` (choice of name may collide with something else, careful) is called, place your `add_action` code inside your widget initialization.

Comment: Also check if(!is_admin()) before enqueue()-ing as there's no point in adding the CSS to the admin area. Or... just switch 'wp_head' with 'wp_footer' and at the CSS at the end :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various approaches ([including this one](http://beerpla.net/2010/01/13/wordpress-plugin-development-how-to-include-css-and-javascript-conditionally-and-only-when-needed-by-the-posts/)), but you could consider, since you're talking about a stylesheet and not a script, simply enqueueing it from the Plugin, regardless of whether the Widget is active. (Which is worse: the few bytes of Widget-specific CSS, or the server overhead to determine if the Widget is active?)

Just add the following to your Plugin file (*outside* of the Widget class definition):

```
<?php
function plugin-name_print_stylesheet() {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* CSS definitions go here */
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'plugin-name_print_stylesheet' );
?>
```

Or, if you've got a .css file with your Widget's stylesheet:

```
<?php
function plugin-name_enqueue_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-name-stylesheet', plugins_dir( 'stylesheet.css', __FILE__ ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'plugin-name_enqueue_stylesheet' );
?>
```

p.s. don't use a generic term such as `my_slider` as a custom-function prefix. You should use your `plugin-slug` instead, as a prefix for all of your Plugin's custom functions.